# GWT: Cyclically loading an Image

Tags: image, gwt, reload

I try to implement kind of a Videostream that relays on simple JPEG Files.
On my server, a JPEG is being created cyclically by an external Camera.
And I just want to include this Picture in my GWT Application.

My first idea to reload the Picture by a Timer was very simple but not so good: The client opens a connection for each reload-cycle, and the Picture flickers (at least in Firefox).

How could I solve these problems? I was thinking about something like "Web-Sockets", but I don't really know how to do.
I want to avoid a single connection for each reload. My idea was to have something like an open connection that just provides a new Picture as often as the Client asks for.

And how could I avoid the flickering when swapping the Picture?

Any ideas are welcome!

Regards, VanDahlen

Comment: does the url changes, per each frame?

Comment: No, the URL is the same for each Picture. I've already added an extra argument for forcing the browser to reload the Pic.

Comment: ok, so my answer should work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Another problem is that we aren't using a Standard Webserver (we are operating on a very rare, uncomfortable and old/deprecated OS... :-S), so I would have to implement the keep alive feature on my own :(

Comment: Keep-alive is a feature of web-servers, they have the control to maintain the socket opened, manage new requests and route then to the appropriate handler (serve files, execute cgi, proxy to app-servers, etc). Anyway if this is your case I doubt you could use websockets or comet with such a webserver.

Comment: @VandDahlen, What the hell are you using as webserver which doesnt support keep-alive?. Persistent connections is a standard since HTTP/1.1 (defined in 1999).

Comment: :D:D We are using QNX Realtime OS (the thing that has now been integrated into Blackberry-Smartphones). It isn't much fun to develop for this System. Someone has written an OWN (!) Webserver that luckily serves at least somes requests...

Answer (score 0):

A solution to avoid flickering is to have two images absolutely positioned in the same location. A timer would load one or other alternatively in each frame. Set a `load` handler to each image, so that it changes the z-index when the image is loaded and it restarts the timer.

Adding an extra parameter to the image url, makes the browser ask the server each time to bypass its cache.

If the time between frames is small, normally the browser will re-use the same connection if  [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) is correctly configured in your server. It normally is enabled with a typical value of 5-15 seconds which you could increase, so if your .jpg images are updated with this periodicity, you don't have to worry and look for a better solution.

I propose a UI solution based on these ideas. But it will work as well if you use a websocket/comet mechanism giving you the last .jpg file in base64 format (just change the url by the value returned).

GWT code:

```java
public void onModuleLoad() {

  final Image i1 = new Image();
  i1.setWidth("400px");

  final Image i2 = new Image();
  i2.setWidth("400px");

  AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();
  panel.add(i1, 0, 0);
  panel.add(i2, 0, 0);
  panel.setSize("600px", "400px");

  RootPanel.get().add(panel);

  // You could change this by base64 data if you use comet/websockets
  String url = "my_image_url.jpg?";

  final Timer loadNext = new Timer() {
    boolean b;
    int c;
    public void run() {
      // the counter parameter forces to load the next frame instead of using cache
      if (b  = !b) {
        i1.setUrl(url + c++);
      } else {
        i2.setUrl(url + c++);
      }
    }
  };

  i1.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
      i1.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(1);
      i2.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(0);
      loadNext.schedule(1000);
    }
  });

  i2.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
      i1.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(0);
      i2.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(1);
      loadNext.schedule(1000);
    }
  });

  loadNext.schedule(1000);
 }
```

If you want to use [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), the code is obviously smaller:

```java
  // You could change this by base64 data if you use comet/websockets
  final String url = "my_image_url.jpg?";

  final GQuery images = $("<img/><img/>").appendTo(document);
  images.css($$("position: fixed, top: 10px, left: 600px, width: 400px"));

  final Timer timer = new Timer() {
    int c;
    public void run() {
      images.eq(c%2).attr("src", url + c++);
    }
  };

  images.bind("load", new Function(){
    public void f() {
      $(this).css($$("z-index: 1")).siblings("img").css($$("z-index: 0"));
      timer.schedule(1000);
    }
  });

  timer.schedule(1000);
```